# Is it true that if $U\ne ℝ^n$ is a subspace of $ℝ^n$ and $x+y$ is in $U$, then $x$ and $y$ are both in $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $U\ne ℝ^n$ is a subspace of $ℝ^n$ and $x+y$ is in $U$, then $x$ and $y$ are both in $U$?

My point of view is that since $x+y$ is the linear combination of $x$ and $y$, so $x, y \in U$, but is it possible we can understand $x+y$ as the single term in $U$ so itself cannot linearly combines to be either $x$ or $y$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  For example, the "$x$-axis" $U = \{(t,0):t \in \Bbb R\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.  We can take
$$
x = (1,1), \quad y = (1,-1)
$$
two elements that are clearly not in $U$.  However, $x + y = (2,0)$, which is an element of $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $x\in\Bbb R^n$ with $x\notin U,$ and let $y=-x.$

Answer (score 0):

Another reason it should have been obvious that the answer is no:

$x+(-x)$ is in *every* subspace. If is proposition were true, then every element would be in the subspace.